# How to use aria-expanded attribute to toggle in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wai-aria

I was converting a theme to react components and my navbar of small device toggle is not working. The **aria-expanded** attr is set to false and on click it will change `aria-expanded=true`. Then I came to know react don't support that. Only by clicking on that it can be toggled. I want to know can this `aria-*` attributes in code?

This is the navbar react component:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <>
        <header id="masthead" class="site-header header-v1" style={{backgroundImage: "none"}}>
            <div class="col-full">
               <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#site-navigation">Skip to navigation</a>
               <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content">Skip to content</a>
               <div class="header-wrap">
                  <div class="site-branding">
                     <a href="index-2.html" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home">
                        
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" aria-label="Primary Navigation">
                     <button class="menu-toggle"  aria-controls="site-navigation" aria-expanded= "false"><span class="close-icon"><i class="po po-close-delete"></i></span><span class="menu-icon"><i class="po po-menu-icon"></i></span><span class=" screen-reader-text">Menu</span></button>
                     <div class="primary-navigation">
                        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu nav-menu"  aria-expanded= "false" >
                           <li class="menu-item"><a href="/">Order Online</a></li>
                           <li class="yamm-fw menu-item menu-item-has-children">
                              <a href="about.html">Pages</a>
                              <ul class="sub-menu">
                                 <li class="menu-item">
                                    <div class="yamm-content">
                                       <div class="kc-elm kc-css-4169277 kc_row">
                                          <div class="kc-row-container  kc-container">
                                             <div class="kc-wrap-columns">
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                                   <div class="kc-col-container">
                                                      <div class="widget widget_nav_menu kc-elm kc-css-1908114">
                                                         <div class="menu-pages-menu-1-container">
                                                            <ul id="menu-pages-menu-5" class="menu">
                                                               <li class="nav-title menu-item"><a href="#">Home Pages</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="index-2.html">Home v1</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="home-v2.html">Home v2</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="home-v3.html">Home v3</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="home-v4.html">Home v4</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="home-v5.html">Home v5</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="home-v6.html">Home v6</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="home-v7.html">Home v7</a></li>
                                                               <li class="nav-title menu-item"><a href="#">User Account</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="login-and-register.html">My Account</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="track-order.html">Track Order</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                         </div>
                                                      </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                                   <div class="kc-col-container">
                                                      <div class="widget widget_nav_menu kc-elm kc-css-2420681">
                                                         <div class="menu-pages-menu-2-container">
                                                            <ul id="menu-pages-menu-6" class="menu">
                                                               <li class="nav-title menu-item"><a href="#">Shop Pages</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html">Shop Grid 3 Column</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-grid-4-column.html">Shop Grid 4 Column</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-grid-6-column.html">Shop Grid 6 Column</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-listing.html">Shop Listing</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-list-2-column.html">Shop List 2 Column</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-list-no-images.html">Shop List No Images</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-list-no-images-parallax.html">Shop List No Image Parallax</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-sidebar-grid-3-column.html">Shop Sidebar Grid 3 Column</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-sidebar-listing.html">Shop Sidebar Listing</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-sidebar-list-2-column.html">Shop Sidebar List 2 Column</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                         </div>
                                                      </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                                   <div class="kc-col-container">
                                                      <div class="widget widget_nav_menu kc-elm kc-css-3102392">
                                                         <div class="menu-pages-menu-3-container">
                                                            <ul id="menu-pages-menu-7" class="menu">
                                                               <li class="nav-title menu-item"><a href="#">Shop Pages – Dark</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-dark-grid-3-column.html">Shop Dark Grid 3 Column</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-dark_list.html">Shop Dark List</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-dark_list-2-column.html">Shop Dark List 2 Column</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-dark-list-no-images.html">Shop Dark List No Images</a></li>
                                                               <li class="nav-title menu-item current_page_parent"><a href="blog.html">Blog Pages</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item current_page_parent"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="blog-full-width.html">Blog Fullwidth</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="blog-full-width-grid.html">Blog Fullwidth Grid</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="blog-grid.html">Blog Grid</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                         </div>
                                                      </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                                   <div class="kc-col-container">
                                                      <div class="widget widget_nav_menu kc-elm kc-css-3447423">
                                                         <div class="menu-pages-menu-4-container">
                                                            <ul id="menu-pages-menu-8" class="menu">
                                                               <li class="nav-title menu-item"><a href="single-product-v1.html">Single Product Style</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="single-product-v1.html">Single Product v1</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="single-product-v2.html">Single Product v2</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="single-product-v3.html">Single Product v3</a></li>
                                                               <li class="nav-title menu-item"><a href="#">Template Pages</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="terms-and-conditions.html">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="faq-v1.html">FAQ v1</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="faq-v2.html">FAQ v2</a></li>
                                                               <li class="menu-item"><a href="404.html">404</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                         </div>
                                                      </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                           <li class="menu-item"><a href="blog.html">News</a></li>
                           <li class="menu-item"><a href="store-locator.html">Store Locator</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="handheld-navigation">
                        <span class="phm-close">Close</span>
                        <ul class="menu">
                           <li class="menu-item "><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html"><i class="po po-pizza"></i>Pizza</a></li>
                           <li class="menu-item "><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html"><i class="po po-burger"></i>Burgers</a></li>
                           <li class="menu-item "><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html"><i class="po po-salads"></i>Salads</a></li>
                           <li class="menu-item "><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html"><i class="po po-tacos"></i>Tacos</a></li>
                           <li class="menu-item "><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html"><i class="po po-wraps"></i>Wraps</a></li>
                           <li class="menu-item "><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html"><i class="po po-fries"></i>Fries</a></li>
                           <li class="menu-item "><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html"><i class="po po-salads"></i>Salads</a></li>
                           <li class="menu-item "><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html"><i class="po po-drinks"></i>Drinks</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </nav>
                  
                  <div class="header-info-wrapper">
                     <div class="header-phone-numbers">
                        <span class="intro-text">Call and Order in</span>
                        <select class="select-city-phone-numbers" name="city-phone-numbers" id="city-phone-numbers">
                           <option value="54 548 779 654">London</option>
                           <option value="33 398 621 710">Paris</option>
                           <option value="718 54 674 021">New York</option>
                        </select>
                        <span id="city-phone-number-label" class="phone-number">54 548 779 654</span>
                     </div>
                     <ul class="site-header-cart-v2 menu">
                        <li class="cart-content ">
                           <a href="cart.html" title="View your shopping cart">
                           <i class="po po-scooter"></i>
                           <span>Go to Your Cart</span>
                           </a>
                           <ul class="sub-menu">
                              <li>
                                 <a href="cart.html" title="View your shopping cart">
                                 <span class="count">2 items</span> <span class="amount">$50.00</span>
                                 </a>
                              </li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="pizzaro-secondary-navigation">
                  <nav class="secondary-navigation" aria-label="Secondary Navigation">
                     <ul class="menu">
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html"><i class="po po-pizza"></i>Pizza</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html"><i class="po po-burger"></i>Burgers</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html"><i class="po po-salads"></i>Salads</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html"><i class="po po-tacos"></i>Tacos</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html"><i class="po po-wraps"></i>Wraps</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html"><i class="po po-fries"></i>Fries</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html"><i class="po po-salads"></i>Salads</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="shop-grid-3-column.html"><i class="po po-drinks"></i>Drinks</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </nav>
                  
               </div>
            </div>
         </header>
    </>
  )
}
```

If you want to see the whole code this is the link:
[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-firefly-0cs0zf?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You have to use state and conditional rendering

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by “react don't support that.”? Changing state on click is at the very core of react, and aria attributes are supported for quite a while now.
Also, it would be great if you could share your code here instead of elsewhere.